# In Spring Framework unable to properly implement Qualifier Annotation

Tags: java, spring

I have an interface -

`ISugar.java` -

```
public interface ISugar {
    public void addSugar();
}
```

I have two classes implementing the interface -

`IceCream.java` -

```
@Component
public class IceCream implements ISugar {

    @Override
    public void addSugar() {
        System.out.println("Sugar added to icecream");
    }

}
```

`Cake.java` -

```
@Component
public class Cake implements ISugar {

    @Override
    public void addSugar() {
        System.out.println("Sugar added to cake");
    }

}
```

Now I have interface -

`IDesert.java` -

```
public interface IDesert {
    public void addSugar();
    public void eatDesert();
}
```

And I have a class implementing the interface -

`Desert.java` -

```
@Component
public class Desert implements IDesert {

    private ISugar sugar;

    @Autowired
    public Desert(ISugar sugar) {
        this.sugar = sugar;
    }
    

    @Override
    public void addSugar() {
        sugar.addSugar();
    }

    @Override
    public void eatDesert() {
        System.out.println("Eating desert");
    }

}
```

I have a xml file -

`applicationContext.xml`

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.ghostcoder.springdemo"/>
```

and my main method is -

```
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = 
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        
        IDesert desert = context.getBean("desert", IDesert.class);
        
        desert.addSugar();
        desert.eatDesert();
        
        context.close();
```

Now, since `ISugar` interface is implemented by two classes - `IceCream` and `Cake` there is ambiguity and as such error as expected -

```
NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException

expected single matching bean but found 2: cake,iceCream
```

Now, I know the solution is to use `Qualifier Annotation` -

ex -

```
Qualifier("iceCream")
```

but I am unsure about where to place the `Qualifier Annotation` in class - `Desert` I have tried to put it above constructor but without success

Comment: You need to put it on the constructor argument.

Comment: Please provide an answer, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The proper syntax is  -

```
    @Autowired
    public Desert(@Qualifier("cake")ISugar sugar) {
        this.sugar = sugar;
    }
```